# Hibernate core dependency with maven (Using intellij)

Tags: hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm getting an error with IntelliJ inspector when I add hibernate dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

The error:

> Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file
>   for artifact
>   'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar':
>   Cannot find parent: org.jboss:jboss-parent for project:
>   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Alpha1
>   for project
>   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Alpha1
>   org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Alpha1
>   from the specified remote repositories: central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2), java.net.m2
>   (http://download.java.net/maven/2/) Path to dependency: 1)
>   com.n0where:beat:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT 2)
>   org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.0.Beta1 (at line 1)

Comment: Adding <scope>provided</scope> gave me at least the jar...

Comment: can you try it from command line `mvn clean install -e` and post the error message stacktrace